# How to create increamental database on mysql

Tags: server, partitioning, mysql, lamp, shredding

I configured a LAMP server on ubuntu 14.04 now earlier I had a single hard disk with 4 TB storage capacity. And so all the database got stored on /var/lib/mysql/ so now the storage is coming to its verge. Now I added another hardisk with 4TB capacity and it is now set as a new volume.

So I want to create volume such as say presently mysql is storing database on a single volume and then when its storage space is coming to verge when I add a new drive as a new volume, I want set in mysql thisvolume such that it will then start storing the data to new volume if my storage space on first volume ended.

If anybody could guide me on it please provide your suggestion.

Comment: If you are running out of storage on a physical disk (volume), you may want to consider using LVM which allows you to span a virtual volume over one or more physical disks.  See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Comment: LVM has a limit of 500TB with XFS but I want greater to PB of data